# Graph Database modeling for Scheduling and Workflow Analysis in Manufacturing

Tags: database-design, neo4j, time-series, graph-databases

We are looking to apply a Graph Database to help us understand bottlenecks, resource utilization, latency issues, and other time related issues related to the workflow in a manufacturing production line.

Google searches have not come up with too much:

https://neo4j.com/blog/streamlining-processes-neo4j-glidewell-laboratories/

Is anyone aware of related work?

I would expect the graph would  minimally need to model:

1. Resources (humans, tool bench (workstations)
2. Operations (skills needed, duration, required sub-assemblies)
3. Sub-assemblies (the materials or derivative outputs from each assembly task).

Is there more?

Answer (score 1):

A graph database would be an excellent choice for modelling many aspects of a manufacturing production line. Your list is a great start.

Consider also that the nodes that represent the stages in a workflow can contain or reference both the static and dynamic data related to each stage. The static data can be things like the instructions or training to perform the task. The dynamic data can be how long the task has taken for the last 10,000 executions or how many failures occurred and when. This kind of information can then be used to detect problems or even anticipate problems in the workflow.

A graph database can be used to describe the sub-assemblies being produced, as you've indicated. Then, taken a step further, they also support supply chain management. You could trace back assembly failures to which batch of sub-assemblies and which batch of components, which component, and which supplier provided the parts that ultimately led to the assembly failure. All of this can help you optimized your supply chain and/or perform recall analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I think graph database is a proper tool to model and analysis the scheduling and workflow in manufacturing.

For example, you could model the resources as vertex, he operation as edge, the sub-assemblies assembled with resources(vertex) and operation(edge) as graph(sub-graph). So you can traverse the workflow from the final artifact to upper layer operations(edge) and upper layer resources(vertex) which depend on recursively into prime resources and operations.Also you could traverse from initial resource step by step to know which final artifact depends on it. And also other graph analysis depends on what you want.